# Issue in Transform Message (Data Weaver) in Mule Studio 6.0.3

Tags: mule, mule-studio, mule-component, dataweave

Just launched mule studio 6.0.3 and trying to use Data Weaver. When I double click the transform message,only blank space coming up.

Whenever I drag and drop any components from palette, i am getting the error as :-
An internal error has occurred.
org/mule/tooling/apikit/common/metadata/resolver/APIkitRouterInvokerMetadataResolver$1$1

Any helps.

Comment: Try to restart Mule studio and check it out? Issue only with Transform message or with all the components?

Comment: hi star, tried restarting and nothing changed...issue with Transform message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There seems to be memory issues, i.e. with the new version there are java heap space requirements and more RAM required. Also, there are focus issues in the palette window. Shut down Studio, come back in, and select another component first, getting the property window, then select the Transform Message component. Don't forget to comment or up-vote if my solution helps.

Answer (score 0):

Hi try to check by restarting your studio, and drag it now. If you did not received yet check whether remaining are working or not.

Answer (score 0):

Even I got same issue but it's resolved from my end.
I think the following solution will work for everyone.
please check the following file:

`APIkitRouterInvokerMetadataResolver$AbstractMetaDataResolver.class` exists in the your Anypoint.

Here is the path where you need to check.
`AnypointStudio\plugins\org.mule.tooling.apikit.common_6.4.3.201802021502\org\mule\tooling\apikit\common\metadata\resolver`